# Get dependency source code with gradle

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to get the sourcecode of a dependency using gradle.
I've found that using the eclipse or the idea plugin may work but I want to keep my code IDE agnostic. Is there a way to obtain the source code for a given dependency? and/or using the eclipse or idea plugin would require me to have those IDE's installed to work?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this was solved since [Gradle 2.0](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-201), the source in my case is in:

`~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/`